# Customizing UICollectionViewCell depending on indexPath

Tags: ios, customization, uicollectionviewcell

Hi i'm trying to customize my collectionviewcell depending on its indexPath but also if I set

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
     [cell addSubView: view];
}
```

the view appear random in some cells.
This is the code I'm using

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    UIView *contentCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    if (row == 0)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
        label.text = @"Test";
        [contentCell addSubview:label];
    }
    [cell addSubview:contentCell];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"container"]];
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(414, 228);
}
```

Comment: "the view appear random in some cells" and not only in the first

Comment: tableview cells are reused. So you need to get rid of the label in the unwanted cells. Adding subviews to cells the way you've done it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read about reusable cells.

you can avoid the problem for now by doing this.

```
if (row == 0)
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
    label.text = @"Test";
    label.tag = 200;
    [contentCell addSubview:label];
}else{
    UIView* lbl = [contentCell viewWithTag:200];
    if(lbl)
       [lbl removeFromSuperView];
}
```

but this will affect the scrolling and memory performance, you can put the label in the cell by default && show/hide it in the if/else blocks

Comment: Thanks Islam. I need to set the content of all 15 cells instead. How can I do that? I have to do this check for all the cells?

Comment: to change the content only

1- First, check if label is created before
2- create it if it's nil
3- change text each time

    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)[contentCell viewWithTag:200];
    if(label == nil){
       label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
       label.tag = 200;
       [contentCell addSubview:label];
    }
    label.text = @"Test";  //whatever text of each cell

Answer (score 0):

You are adding view several times as a subview. Cells are reused due to "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier", so after you scroll up and down, you get back existing view, which already has subview added.

You should read more about reusing cells.

One way to avoid that behavior is to create all views when you create a cell and just show / hide them.
Otherwise create cells with different identifier for different rows - in your case for row 0.

Comment: And how can I show/hide them if I can't check the indexPath?

Comment: You can base hiding / showing based on indexPath, but you can't add a subview based on that. You can also add subview and add "tag" to it, and always check if it exists and if you need to add it.